# Handle multi-label dataset in classification using j48 tree

Tags: weka

I'm trying to use j48 tree to perform a text categorization task. I read a lot of papers and websites that explain how to use classification having datasets whose data are single labeled.
In my case I have only multi-labeled data in my training set, what can I have to treat these data in a single decision tree? Or the only solution is generating many trees as many as the number of the labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tree with adapted entropy formula. You must define beforehand if your dataset has hierachical labels:
[papers and code](http://www.aber.ac.uk/en/cs/research/cb/dss/phenotype/)